# A game from Exercise in Artin's Algebra (Chapter 2 M.13)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found an interesting problem in Chapter 2 for Artin's Algebra (2nd Ed) in the Miscellaneous section that I haven't been able to figure out. The text of the problem is quoted below.

> M.13 (a game) The starting position is the point $(1,1)$, and a permissible "move" replaces a point $(a,b)$ by one of the points $(a+b, b)$ or $(a, a+b)$. So the position after the first move will be either $(2,1)$ or $(1,2)$. Determine the points that can be reached.

I've written a small python script to generate and plot the point and I saw the pattern in the image  but no idea how to come up with a general description of the points.

link to code is [here](http://repl.it/ufZ).

[image]

I appreciate a solution or a link to a solution.

Comment: Maybe note that each "move" is multiplication by $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Hint: Consider $\gcd(a,b)$ for the points that can be reached.

Comment: @angryavian Is there a link between the answer given below by "2000" and the two matrices you provided? I can see how the two matrices provide a linear transformation for the game but not sure how to get to gcd from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is taking you through all pairs of $(a,b)$ such that $a ,b > 0 $ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

**Proof**: Take $A$ be the set of all pairs that we get from the game.

We first show that if $(a,b) \in A$ then $\gcd(a,b)=1$: it follows form [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Euclidean_algorithm).

Now by induction we show that if $a,b > 0$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $(a,b) \in A$: we know this is true for $a,b<2$, now if this is true for $a,b<n$ then this is true for $a=n$ or $b=n$, because for instance if $2 \leq a=n$ and $1 \leq b<n$ then by induction hypothesis we know $(a-b,b)$ is in $A$ and by the game rule we conclude $(a,b) \in A$.

> **Hint for Patterns in the image**:
>   For every irreducible $\frac{m}{n}$ we have infinite $k$ such that $\frac{mk+1}{nk}$ is irreducible.
>   **Proof**: Set $k=an, \quad a\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented Euclidean Algorithms before but here it's a constructive way to look at it instead of recursive. Just out of curiosity, do you know of an explanation or more information on the pattern that emerges in the image?

Comment: I believe in this image some points are missed. for example: (1,n) , (n,1) ,(n,n-1) , ... for large n.

Comment: Accepted, although I still don't know what could be the issue with the code. I've gone through it multiple times and seems to be correct. I've edited the question to include a link to my code in all cases

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about python. but i guess "N_steps" in line 29 is not enough to show you for example: (1,101),(101,100),... because for this pairs you need at least 100 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Can't add a comment so posting as an answer:

As pointed out by angryavian, the final co-ordinates are obtained by:

$$ E_1E_2 ...E_n\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} m \\ n \end{bmatrix} $$

where each $ E_i$ is one of the two matrices

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} $

This means

$$ E_n^{-1} ...E_2^{-1}E_1^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} m \\ n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

But each $ E_i^{-1} $ encodes a step of Euclid's Algorithm, and the remainder is on the R.H.S. This implies $ gcd(m,n) =1 $